# Why getClientOriginalName() doesn't work to get the original name of a uploaded file?

Tags: symfony, filenames, email-attachments

To attach uploaded files to an email, I use the function getClientOriginalName() and in the receipted email, the name of the file is always the basename, without extension.

I use a code I've found in https://hotexamples.com/site/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Falexander-schranz%2Fsulu-website-user-bundle
I have tried multiple way to write the search of the original name, and I found always the same basename
My function is :

```
public function send($from, $to, $sujet, $body, $attachments = [])
    {
    $message = new \Swift_Message($sujet, $body);
    $message->setFrom($from);
    $message->setTo($to);
    if (count($attachments) > 0) {
        foreach ($attachments as $file) {
            switch ($file) {
...
                    case $file instanceof UploadedFile:
                        $nomfic = $file->getClientOriginalName();             
                        break;
                        }
    $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($path),$nomfic);
```

The beginning of the dump of the attachment is :

```
 0 => UploadedFile {#16 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "etiquettes.pdf"
    -mimeType: "application/pdf"
    -error: 0
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php4Koz9N"
    basename: "php4Koz9N"
    pathname: "/tmp/php4Koz9N"
```

I hope to have "etiquettes.pdf" instead of "php4Koz9N" !!

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClientOriginalName` returns name uploaded file in the browser (warning! it's unsafe). The real file is in `/tmp/phpXXXXX`.

So, your code may be ...

```
<?php

$attach = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedfile->getRealPath(), $uploadedfile->getMimeType());
$attach->setFilename($uploadedfile->getClientOriginalName()); # Only if you rely in your client. That is, never!
$message->attach($attach);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me ! using directly \Switch_Attachment induce an error 500 :  "attempted to load class swift_attachment". What is strange for me, is that using what I have found in Symfony's documentation " $nomfic = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension();" doesn't work more. The $snomfic is replaced by the same phpXXXX... !

Comment: `\Swift_Attachment` is ok. (Example: https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#changing-the-disposition ) Do you run the funcion in a Symfony Controller context?. If not, Do you include autoloader?

Comment: For this function, I'm not in a Controller, I'm in a  folder src/Utils In Symfony4, I don't know how include autoloader... But my problem is really to attach my file with the name I choose !!

Comment: So, you must include the file "vendor/autoload.php" for autoload classes. And if you are out of Controller context, you can't access to UploadedFile. If the file is uploaded via html form, you must move /tmp/phpXXXXX file to a safe directory and execute your Util late.

Comment: Thanks, that works like that. My original problem is always the same : I can't attach an uploaded file to a message, with a name and an extension I have chosen. Eventually, what I do is : save the file (move), with my chosen name and extension, and after put it in the $attachments array.